# Unexpected EOF while parsing; trying calculate mean/max/min of each line reading in

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

the data looks like this:

```
line = infile.readlines()
line

['56047257 16 17 19 16 12 15 12 20 58 123 59\n',
 '97231934 18 16 13 19 16 12 13 18 72 101 55\n',
 ....same]
```

I want to get the average of the 2 to 9 column and get max and min of 2 to 12 column by using the loop below, but it keep giving me an error:

```
 File "<string>", line unknown

    ^
 SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

This is what my code looks like :

```
def main():
    #read data in
    infile = open('data.txt', 'r')
    sun = 0.0
    count = 0
    line = infile.readline()
    while line != "":

        ID = line.split(" ")
        min_val = float('inf')
        max_val = -float('inf')
        count_min = 0
        count_max = 0
        for xStr in line.split(' ')[1:9]:
            sun = sun + eval(xStr)
            count = count + 1
            avg = round(sun / count, 2)
            val = eval(xStr)
            if val < min_val:
                min_val = val
                count_min = 1
                elif val == min_val:
                count_min += 1

            if val > max_val:
                max_val = val
                count_max = 1
            elif val == max_val:
                count_max += 1
    line = infile.readline()

    print (ID, ' ',avg,' ',min_val,' ',max_val)

main()
```

Comment: Could you add which line the error is on?

Comment: Using `eval` on an empty string results in an EOF error. Is xStr ever an empty string?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you have an infinite `while` loop

Comment: That seems to be the case. Is that indentation error present in the actual code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take note of the issues raised in the comments section of your post, but with that said, this is a much easier way of getting your desired output:

```
def main():
    #read data in
    infile = open('data.txt', 'r')
    average = max_val = min_val = 0.0
    count1=count2 = 0
    line = infile.readlines()
    for x in [x.strip().split() for x in line[:9]]:
        x = ID =map(int, x) 
        average = (average + (sum(x)/len(x)))/len(x)
        print average
    for x in [x.strip().split() for x in line[:12]]:
        x = map(int, x)
        val=max(x)
        if count1 !=0 and val>max_val:
            max_val = val
        val=min(x)
        if count2 !=0 and val<min_val:
            min_val = val
        if count1==0:
            max_val=max(x)
            min_val=min(x)
            count1=count2=1      

    print (ID, ' ',average,' ',min_val,' ',max_val)

main()
```

Note: You should try not assign `infinty` to variables. There are usually always better alternatives